# Angular2-crumbs and lazy loading component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, breadcrumbs

I am trying to use [Angular2-crumbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-crumbs) with [lazy loader components](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html) in my project. Somehow breadcrumb is working fine but my lazy loader component doesn't load and not throwing any error in the `console` either.

What I have understand from the [Angular2-crumbs code](https://github.com/emilol/angular-crumbs/tree/angular2-crumbs/demo/src/app) that it works only with children components. Since my requirement is to use lazy loading so what I did is that I am redirecting from `app` to `root` component where I have all lazy loading components under the children of `root` component.

The arrangement of my code is given below:

**app.routing.modules.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 {path: '', redirectTo: 'root', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
    CoreModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
 ]
 providers: []
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**root-routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '', component: RootComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
        {
          path: 'screen/home', component: HomeComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Home' }, children:[
             { path: 'orders', loadChildren: './../app/orders/module#Module', data: { breadcrumb: 'Order management'} },
             { path: 'stocks', loadChildren: './../app/stocks/module#Module', data: { breadcrumb: 'Stock management' } },
        ]
      }
   ]}

  ])
],
 exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class RootRoutingModule {}
```

**root.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
            declarations: [
                HomeComponent,
                RedirectComponent,
                RootComponent
            ],
            imports: [
                CoreModule,
                BrowserModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                BreadcrumbModule.forRoot(),
                HttpClientModule,
                RootRoutingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                BannerService,
                BlockService,
                CanDeactivateGuard,
                ConfirmationService,
                CoreService,
                GenericService,
                HttpClient,
                MessageService,
                RedirectComponent,
            ]
        })
        export class RootModule {
        }
```

**root.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'root',
  templateUrl: 'src/root/root.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['src/root/root.component.css']
})
export class RootComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**root.component.html**

```
<breadcrumb></breadcrumb>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

There is no extra documentation provided in the [Angular2-crumb repo](https://github.com/emilol/angular-crumbs/tree/angular2-crumbs/demo/src/app) so I don't have any clue how to solve this problem.

If anyone can help me I would appreciate you in advance.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this issue by doing some minor changes in root-routing.modules.ts below:

**root-routing.modules.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
     { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'screen/home', component: RootComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Home' }, children: [
         { path: 'orders', loadChildren: './../app/orders/module#Module', data: { breadcrumb: 'Order management'} },
         { path: 'stocks', loadChildren: './../app/stocks/module#Module', data: { breadcrumb: 'Stock management' } },
      ]}
  ])
],
 exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class RootRoutingModule {}
```

So my conclusion after checking the Angular2-crumbs code again is that it works with first children component.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this.

Track the last index in the *ngfor loop of the breadCrumb component.

Angular exposes local variables for ngfor to track elements of the loop.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Replace the customizable code mentioned in the angular-crumbs customizable code. I am demonstrating below using a bootstrap example.

From:

```
<breadcrumb #parent>
   <ol class="breadcrumb">
     <ng-template ngFor let-route [ngForOf]="parent.breadcrumbs">
       <li *ngIf="!route.terminal" class="breadcrumb-item">
         <a href="" [routerLink]="[route.url]">{{ route.displayName }}</a>
       </li>
       <li *ngIf="route.terminal" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"> 
            {{ route.displayName }}</li>
     </ng-template>
   </ol>
</breadcrumb> }
```

Change To:

```
<breadcrumb #parent>
   <ol class="breadcrumb">
     <ng-template ngFor let-route [ngForOf]="parent.breadcrumbs" let-lastIndex="last">
       <li *ngIf="!lastIndex" class="breadcrumb-item">
         <a href="" [routerLink]="[route.url]">{{ route.displayName }}</a>
       </li>
       <li *ngIf="lastIndex" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"> 
            {{ route.displayName }}</li>
     </ng-template>
   </ol>
</breadcrumb> }
```

The value of lastIndex will be a boolean value. Here, when we know the breadcrumb ngfor loop is at last value, mark it as active.

That is how you solve the fantastic angular-crumbs library problem with Lazy Loading. Let me know if you need an example.